# Database Access and Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a database access with table "students" and 3 column "ID", "Email" and "Name".
In combobox i have insert connection to database at column "name". After selection name from combobox is possible show a messagebox with the id and email from database in corresponding to the selected name?

Comment: If I m not wrong, You want to show ID and email of that student on click of the name in combo box?

Comment: ex: in combobox selecte "john" after selection show the id and email of john "messagebox.show(id,email of john); if selecte "anna" the id and email of anna

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) event of ComboBox. You can use in a method, as
on ComboBox Selection:

```
//this method you will get after you double click the ComboBox in the Form       
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        comboBox1.Click += new EventHandler(this.IWantToDisplayMessageBox);
    }
}

public void IWantToDisplayMessageBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("student ID and email");
}
```

Where, you may want to have "select" string at 0th index of ComboBox. Now only thing you need to do is, call the Database accessor you created and provide the ID and Email of that student selected in MessageBox